# What is the best .NET API to build a REST service

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf, rest

What is the best API to build a rest service: WCF and ASP MVC. What are the pros and cons of each approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the moment WCF is relatively painful to build pure REST/HATEOAS api. Especially if you want to have unit tests. ASP MVC is targeted at more UI oriented projects. You may want to wait until Microsoft releases [WCF Web API](http://wcf.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=WCF%20HTTP) or use [OpenRasta](http://trac.caffeine-it.com/openrasta).

Comment: I would really look into  http://www.servicestack.net/ as another alternative as well.  But Dmitry's answer is spot on with the issues between trying it with MVC or WCF as they are.

Answer (score 1):

A lot of it would depend on what your team is more experience with.

You can pull it off with either one (WCF or ASP.NET MVC) but if your team is already comfortable with MVC you might find it easier to follow that route rather than start from scratch on WCF.

This is a good book on the subject: [http://www.amazon.com/Effective-REST-Services-via-NET/dp/0321613252](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321613252)

Answer (score 0):

A lot of what to use depends on what you are going to do with it, are you looking for a was to update view elements with jQuery? then using Asp.net MVC is the way to do it, for a API to be accessed by external users the it depends on your view of open source, if you group is ok with open source then I would say take a look at  [OpenRasta](http://trac.caffeine-it.com/openrasta), otherwise take a look at [WCF Web API](http://wcf.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=WCF%20HTTP), it's just not as mature are OpenRasta.